# Remove special characters from list

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a list which I want to prepare to be parsed into HTML table. 
Currently list is:

```
[<tr>
    <td valign="top">Test32</td>
    <td valign="top">24-11-2016, 08:54</td>
    <td valign="top">1</td>
    <td valign="top">1</td>
    <td valign="top">Draw</td>
    <td valign="top">3</td>
</tr>, <tr>
    <td valign="top">Test32</td>
    <td valign="top">24-11-2016, 08:54</td>
    <td valign="top">2</td>
    <td valign="top">2</td>
    <td valign="top">Draw</td>
    <td valign="top">10</td>
</tr>]
```

I would like for "[]" and "," between two `tr` to be removed. What would be the best way to remove a comma since I have some other commas in `list` as well which means I cannot either replace or use `regex` in a simple way?

EDIT:

Problem was with wrongly generated list. Was fixed with converting variable to `str` and using `.replace` method

Comment: Do you want the content of your list to be in single string?

Comment: If is it a list of strings `x`, then `"".join(x)`.

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri Yes, this exactly what I want in the end

Comment: That is nt a valid Python list. Please correct the code!

Comment: @Klaud D. Thank you for pointing it out. It was supposed to be a list but actually was not what caused problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `</tr>,`  with special char sequence like `</tr>$$$` then split the result string with that char sequence `$$$`.